# Error trying to import Gradle Project to Android Studio existing project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to import 3 Gradle Projects I used in all my apps with utilities to a new project.

I create the new project and then File -> Project Structure -> + -> Import Gradle Project [image: Projects selected to be imported]

Then I click Finish but those 3 projects do not appear in the modules list

[image: Modules list, without the 3 projects that should have been imported]

No error has appeared yet. But when I click Ok there I do got 4 IDE fatal errors:

1/4

```
Element: class org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyFileImpl because: different providers: SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://F:/development/workspaces/Orchestram/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=16}}(2177d6ca); SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://F:/development/workspaces/Orchestram/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=16}}(16a77aa0)
```

2/4

```
Element: class com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsFileImpl because: file://F:/development/workspaces/Orchestram/app/callRemoteService/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/qbitera/CallRemoteService/R.class is invalid
```

3/4

```
Element: class org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyFileImpl because: different providers: SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://F:/development/workspaces/Orchestram/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=16}}(344f03e4); SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://F:/development/workspaces/Orchestram/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=16}}(4940c49e)
```

4/4

```
Error while applying changes
```

This is my build.gradle before trying to import those modules (it does not change)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qbitera.cerqana.orchestram"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And the settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
```

Of course if I try to just include the *implementation project(':callRemoteService')* line in the Gradle it fails. But if try to import againg the modules from the Project Structure, it says that it is already on the project

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to settings.gradle at the root folder:

```
include ':app'
include ':your_module'
include ':your_second_module'
include ':you_got_the_point'
```